# How to hide "idle" (both CPU and RAM) processes in top?

Tags: linux, awk, grep, top-command

I have a linux command based on top that outputs my current tasks snapshot (I've assembled it from various SE topics so it may not be optimal but it works for me):

```
top -bn 1 -i | grep "^ " | awk '{ printf("%s%s%s\n","
{CPU:"$9",","MEM:"$10",","CMD:"$12"}"); }' | tail -n +2 | gawk '{ 
print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }'
```

The output is something like this:

> [2018-11-20 18:09:11] {CPU:0.0,MEM:0.2,CMD:uwsgi}
>   [2018-11-20 18:09:11] {CPU:0.0,MEM:0.0,CMD:uwsgi}
>   [2018-11-20 18:09:11] {CPU:0.0,MEM:0.0,CMD:nginx}
>   [2018-11-20 18:09:11] {CPU:0.0,MEM:0.0,CMD:nginx}
>   [2018-11-20 18:09:11] {CPU:0.0,MEM:0.0,CMD:nginx}

Actually, I get like 300 lines for every execution of my command. 
I would like to remove the lines that have "CPU:0.0,MEM:0.0".

I've tried: `top -i`but that removes all "idle" tasks, which means "CPU:0.0" - however, that way, I am losing all the tasks like: CPU:0.0,MEM:0.2 (which I want to keep)

Perhaps add an if-then-else somehow inside the awk part of the command? I've tried to hack it but it just doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please post output of your `top` command itself we may do it in single `awk` or `sed` itself too. And could save many sub processes to be created too.

Comment: add the condition `$9+$10` before the statement, which will filter out the records where both are zero.  e.g. `awk '$9+$10{printf ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep will do:

```
... | grep -v "CPU:0.0,MEM:0.0"
```

From the man page:

> ```
> -v, --invert-match
>     Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
> ```

Comment: we live in such a world where 2 days is enough to write some code and test that it works normally ;)
Anyway, thanks for your help, it's a simple fix that gives me confidence that it'll work fine!